# How twitter ios app is doing to push the profile page with a new UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I wondering how Twiter is doing, in the ios app, to push a profile viewController with a new navbar or a new navigationController above the current viewController ?

[image]

Comment: I know this is too late but I just answered an identical question before I saw yours :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47377166/3405387

Answer (score 0):

In your stoyboard you have your UITabBarController connected to the UIUserController. Embed a UINavigationController between them and you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationController is probably the same. What seems to be a custom navigation bar is actually a transparent navigation bar and a UIView coming from the top behind it.

Comment: The uinavigationController is not the same. It seems be a new uinavigationController which is pushed above the current. May be it's a modal with a custom transition ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to hide the Navigation bar in viewWillAppear and show it for the pushed view controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

explanation can be found

https://medium.com/@qbo/push-page-with-without-navigation-bar-eb3cea35178d